# Ember no method save on this.get('store').save()

Tags: ember.js

Feel like I'm asking too much Ember questions lately, trust me I'm really trying by myself before every question and hopefully I'll get the whole picture going 'cause as of right now it's been two steps forward, one backwards.

This [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/UcUkOZu/2/edit) ilustrates what I'm doing. It won't run since I can't load the localadapter_storage library, maybe there's a way to load it into jsbin but if that's so I don't know how to do it.

The problem I have is as follows:

I have the hability to create new posts and to edit old ones. When editing old ones I can't `save` the changes via `this.get('store').save();` (have tried `commit()` also) since it says `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'` The save for the new posts is working properly.

I've compared the issue with other working examples of ember using the local adapter and I've tried to step by step ember.js and ember-data.js but I'm really not that versed yet. According to the error it's like it doesn't know where to apply the .save().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `record.save()`.  You don't need to access the store when you're saving, so in your case it would be something like, `this.get('controller.model').save();`

Comment: As simple as that, besides the fix I thanks the `You don't need to access the store when you're saving` that's my today's learning. Will keep trying as long as it takes! Thanks kingpin.

Comment: hahah, you'll be a pro in a few months, it's a little bit of a learning curve, but then it's super powerful.

Comment: that's the spirit, all we need is positive feedback and some good challenges to keep it rolling. Can't wait till I get there so I can have more answers than question! (accepting the answer as soon as it lets me) Thanks again.